# Undefined method when combining an array of letters with reduce

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
a = "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"

r = a.reduce(){|a, e|
  puts "a class: " + a.class.to_s;
  a + e;

  puts "a: " + a.to_s()
  puts "e: " + e.to_s
}
```

produces the following output:

```
a class: String
a: h
e: e
a class: NilClass
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
(repl):5:in `block in <main>'
(repl):3:in `each'
(repl):3:in `reduce'
(repl):3:in `<main>'
```

But when I run the code without the `puts` calls, it runs fine. Can someone provide clarification on this issue?

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages omitting empty argument lists, so `reduce { |a,e|` and `to_s` are the correct form here. Likewise `;` is omitted except in cases when it's strictly necessary, such as putting multiple statements on one line.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs fine"?

Comment: @sawa, it presumably means that it `reduce`s the array successfully to a string without raising an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your code ever so slightly (e.g. to the following), the problem is fixed:

```
a = "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"

r = a.reduce{|a, e|
  puts "a class: " + a.class.to_s
  puts "a: " + a.to_s
  puts "e: " + e.to_s
  a + e
}
```

The reason is that the block you passed to `reduce`, i.e. the code within the `{}`, evaluates to `nil` because the last statement `puts` returns `nil`.

With the fixed code above, the block evaluates ("returns") the result of the last statement `a + e`, which is probably what you want to reduce the character array.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yeah, I admit I was lazy... fixed it now.